# Rails 4 sharing form partials and strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have a contact form partial that I include in two different forms on my app. I was wondering if there is a better approach to strong parameters than duplicating the permitted params in each respective controller?

Users controller:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, contact_attributes: [:city, :state])
end
```

User Applications controller:

```
def user_application_params
  params.require(:user_application).permit(:gender, :birthdate, 
                 user_attributes: [contact_attributes: [:city, :state]])
end
```

So ideally this code would be in one place, I'm not sure how to achieve this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me say, whitelisting your all params automatically is a hack that might be ok in some situations but could cause some substantial security risks in others and exposes you to risk as your codebase evolves (so it's never really ok).  Here's a much better way to solve the problem that is about as easy and should work in just about all situations.

Instead, write a controller concern.  This is just a module that goes into your `app/controllers/concerns` directory.

so create `app/controllers/concerns/shared_contact_permitted_attributes.rb` as follows:

```
module SharedContactPermittedAttributes
  def shared_contact_permitted_attributes
    contact_attributes: [:city, :state]
  end
end
```

Then in whatever controller you want it to show up in, add `include SharedContactPermittedAttributes` at the top and use the method defined in the module in your strong params.  For example:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, shared_contact_permitted_attributes)
end
```

Then you're done!

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was permitting all parameters and blacklisting certain ones. The blacklist params is a lot shorter than the whitelist.

```
params[:profile].permit!.except(user_attributes: [role_ids: []])
```

This allowed me to easily reuse certain form partials.

Comment: This is REALLY not a good idea as it automatically leaves you open to inadvertently white-listing potentially hazardous attributes as your code-base evolves.  Concerns are a much better way to accomplish this.